# How To Return Aggregated Result of Last Actor?

Tags: akka.net

I have setup ActorSystem to perform MapReduce on a collection of data. I have now got last Actor to collate all results. How can i channel the result back to the "service" which initated this Actor System  ?

```
//in below call i wire up all Actors
var getActorSystem = CreateActorSystem();

//I wait for ActorSystem to complete
getActorSystem.WhenTerminated.Wait();
```

How do i get the result from last Actor in ActorSystem which now has the final result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the Ask functionality in Akka.NET. Ask will return a Task and thus you will need to wait for its completion after which you can get access to the response from Task.Result.

The docs cover this scenario http://getakka.net/docs/working-with-actors/sending-messages#ask-send-and-receive-future.